# Op-amp replace problem

Tags: operational-amplifier

Can we use TLV2221 op-amp for differential to single ended output,in place of TLV9062 opamp,or any issue if TLV9062 replaced with TLV2221.can anyone explain?

Comment: What do the **datasheets** tell you? If I said: "*You can **ALWAYS** use a TLV2221 instead of a TLV9062"*, would you believe me? There needs to be only one feature that the TLV9062 has but the TLV2221 does not have to not be able to replace one with the other. Hint: what does the SHDN pin do? Do all opamps have that? Does the TLV2221 work on a supply voltage of 1.8 V? Does the TLV9062? Without knowing **how you will use these opamps** (that means schematics, performance you need etc.) it is **impossible** to answer your question.

Comment: The TLV9062 is the RRIO version, only the outputs of the TLV2221 can go between the power supplies, i.e. an  RRO only version. What would justify the exchange? Just one of many questions.

Answer (score 0):

[So check this out](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/raqs/raq-issue-145.html#) in order to figure out certain parameters that you might want to take into considertion while designing a **Differential to Single Ended Output Op Amp**

[TLV2221](https://www.ti.com/product/TLV2221#product-details##description) when compared to [TLV9062](https://www.ti.com/product/TLV9062#product-details##description) has significantly less slew rate compared to 9026. The common mode rejection ratio of 9062 is better than 2221. The voltage bandwidth you'll work with is better on 9062 compared to 2221.

So I suggest you stick with the 9062. Hope this helped.